# Cost-effective way to convert a clip-on condenser to wireless?

Tags: microphone, wireless, phantom, sennheiser

I have a clip-on condenser microphone, the [Shure PGA98H-XLR](https://www.thomann.de/gb/shure_pga98h_xlr.htm), which I use for my trombone. It ends in an XLR adapter which clips onto my belt, and I can plug an XLR cable into that.

For about 90% of my gigs a wired microphone is fine, but occasionally it would be much better if I could go wireless.

From what I can see, the best way to do this would be something like a Sennheiser G2 system using a plug-on transmitter, although since I'll need phantom power this would have to be one of the high end ones such as the [SKP 500 G2](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Sennheiser-SKP-500-G2-plug-on-transmitter-with-48v-Phantom-Power-830-866MHz/192540546969?hash=item2cd44f9799:g:3bAAAOSw1URauXI7); even a used one on eBay is about £200, then I'd need a receiver which would take the total to ~£250.

I'm wondering if it can be done any cheaper than this, since I won't need it all that frequently? Perhaps using something like a small battery-operated phantom power unit (e.g. [Millenium PP2B](https://www.thomann.de/gb/millenium_pp2b.htm)) and then a standard (non-phantom-powering) G2 beltpack trasnmitter, for a total of about £120?

The linked power unit is still rather bulky though (it has two in/outputs, I'd only need one) and has no belt clip so not ideal. Does anyone have any better suggestions, or thoughts about the two setups I suggested?

Comment: To need a mic on a trombone you must be playing in some what large venues. I'm sure most places would have the receiver for a sennheiser transmitter right?

Comment: Sure, although you have to match G2/G3 systems as well as frequency bands right? And the bulk of the cost here is plug-on trasmitter since it needs to provide power.

Comment: g2 and g3 are cross compatible as long as you have they have a matching frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a trombone player, you play an instrument with an extremely wide dynamic range. Unfortunately if you attempt to run this wirelessly you will run into big issues with companding (compression/expansion) over the wireless audio channel. The cheaper you go, the worse these issues will be. Unfortunately it will make your instrument sound rubbish.

If you are intent on using a "cheaper" device, the most cost-effective device would be the Rode TX-XLR unit. This transmits digitally and will be less affected by companding which is prevalent across all the analogue and hybrid devices.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that a RODE system like that would be better than a Sennheiser G2 system for this reason then?

Comment: Intuitively yes. I have a similar Rode device, but have not tried it on a trombone. Unfortunately I suspect Rode have not tested their device on a trombone, so I suggest you test it if at all possible before you buy. The Rode device will have been stress tested for dialogue. Trombone is a much higher dynamic range. Being a digital device though would indicate it is probably more resilient in this regard.